# jQuery math operation output to input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to code a form to calculate the price of an item. Its consists of a number of inputs for the user to enter the price of an item, if it will be on discount, and the discount percentage after which it will automatically calculate the discounted price.

The discount percentage and the discounted price are hidden upon pageload, and are displayed only when the "Yes" discount radio button is checked.Both of these are able to be hidden and displayed just fine, but i am currently unable to calculate the discounted price as there seems to be an issue with my jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Code Extract(jQuery):

```
 <!--calculates the discounted price-->
    if($('#BizAddItemRadioYes').is(':checked')) {

        $('#BizAddItemPercent').change(function(){

            var percent=$('#BizAddItemPercent').val();
            var price=$('#BizAddItemPrice').val();
            var discountpercent=percent / 100;
            var discountprice=price/discountpercent;
            $('#BizAddItemDiscountPrice').val(discountprice);

        });

    }
```

Code Extract(HTML):

```
<div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
    <label for='BizAddItemPrice'>Price:</label>
    <input class='BizAddItemInput' type='number' id='BizAddItemPrice' name='BizAddItemPrice'>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
    <label>Discount:</label>
    <input type="radio" class='BizAddItemInput' value="Yes" id='BizAddItemRadioYes' name='BizAddItemDiscount'>Yes
    <input type="radio" checked='checked' class='BizAddItemInput' value="No"  id='BizAddItemRadioNo' name='BizAddItemDiscount'>No
    </span></span>
</div>


<div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
    <div class='BizAdditemDiscountDetails'>
        <label for='BizAddItemPercent'>Discount Percentage</label>
        <input class='BizAddItemInput' type='number' id='BizAddItemPercent' name='BizAddItemPercent'>%
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
    <div class='BizAdditemDiscountDetails'>
        <label for='BizAddItemDiscountPrice'>Discounted Price:</label>
        <input class='BizAddItemInput' type='number' id='BizAddItemDiscountPrice' name='BizAddItemDiscountPrice' readonly >
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in logic calculating discounted price

Try this:

```
$('#BizAddItemRadioYes').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
    $('#BizAddItemPercent').change(function(){
       var percent=$('#BizAddItemPercent').val();
        var price=$('#BizAddItemPrice').val();
        var discountpercent=percent / 100;
        var discountprice=price * discountpercent;

        $('#BizAddItemDiscountPrice').val(price - discountprice);

    });

   }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHRYw/

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic problem with your script, not much else:

You attach the change function only if the radio is checked, what you mean to do is calculate it only when the radio is checked but the binding should always be there.

If you change the if and put in the change bind you get this http://jsfiddle.net/74WCF/2/

```
$('#BizAddItemPrice').on('change', function(){
    if($('#BizAddItemRadioYes').is(':checked')) {

            var percent=$('#BizAddItemPercent').val();
            var price=$('#BizAddItemPrice').val();
            var discountpercent=percent / 100;
            var discount=price*discountpercent;
            $('#BizAddItemDiscountPrice').val(price-discount);;
    }
});
```

In the example it's bound only to the price change, but there are a lot of things missing, like rounding, the same binding should be added on the radios and the other value input. But the fiddle should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your discount price is wrong?

Try to calculate it this way: `discountprice = price-(price/100)*percent`

http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4kG/